# Luigi disrupting parallel processes of one of its Tasks?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I'm using Spotify's [https://github.com/spotify/luigi](http://luigi) module to schedule tasks. Within my script, I have defined several luigi.Task's - the majority of which call Python scripts via subprocess.Popen(), and pertain to a mostly linear dependency graph.

My final 2 tasks are biggest. Within the Python script that each calls (again, via subprocess), the job is parallelized across ~8 CPU's. Put simply, when I run each script on the command line or via subprocess.Popen in an iPython console, the script parallelizes as it should and takes a given time X to complete. However, when run via luigi, each script takes far, far longer than time X, and does not parallelize as it should. I'm doing everything on an EC2 instance with 32 cores and ~244GB of RAM.

luigi has a default --workers command-line parameter. For what it's worth, each of my problematic tasks takes its own command-line parameter which specifies the number of jobs to run within; for clarity, I've defined a new command-line parameter in luigi called --njobs which I pass to each script. Then, setting --workers to 1 (default) or 2 (such that problematic_task_1 and problematic_task_2 run simultaneously), I still experience the same slowdown.

Thoughts, SA?